# How to combine mutable JSON objects using PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, fullcalendar

## The Project

I'm currently using [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) to display a constantly changing calendar containing various information. When the user clicks on a day, a modal appears displaying a title, description, and links to files.

My current JSON object looks like:

```
{
    "title": "myTitle",
    "start": "2015-12-18T09:00:00",
    "end": "2015-12-18T10:00:00",
    "item_number": "1",
    "description": "Test Document",
    "items":[
        {
            "docName":"Document 1",
            "docUrl":"docName.pdf"
        },
        {
            "docName":"Document 2",
            "docUrl":"docName-2.pdf"
        },
        {
            "docName":"Document 3",
            "docUrl":"docName-3.pdf"
        },
    ],
    "id": 0
}
```

#### The setup:

There are three teams:

1. Schedulers - This team modifies the schedule, then notifies me to edit the JSON file, updating the calendar.
2. Editors - This team creates then sends the documents to me to upload to the server and modify the JSON file.
3. Developers - This team puts everything together. Some days, you might have 60-90 edits throughout the day.

Currently, the JSON document is manually modified by the developers while we test.

#### My Plan:

1. Since the schedulers are not very tech-savvy, what I'm doing is having them modify a Google Spreadsheet that is published as a CSV and converted to JSON through PHP. This creates the following JSON object:

   ```
   {
       "title": "myTitle",
       "start": "2015-12-18T09:00:00",
       "end": "2015-12-18T10:00:00",
       "item_number": "1",
       "description": "Test Document"
   }
   ```
2. The editors will create their documents and upload using [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). A JSON object is created referencing the file(s):

   ```
   "items":[
       {
           "docName":"Document 1",
           "docUrl":"docName.pdf"
       },
       {
           "docName":"Document 2",
           "docUrl":"docName-2.pdf"
       },
       {
           "docName":"Document 3",
           "docUrl":"docName-3.pdf"
       }
   ]
   ```
3. The two JSON objects are combined and an ID is assigned:

   ```
   {
       "title": "myTitle",
       "start": "2015-12-18T09:00:00",
       "end": "2015-12-18T10:00:00",
       "item_number": "1",
       "description": "Test Document",
       "items":[
           {
               "docName":"Document 1",
               "docUrl":"docName.pdf"
           },
           {
               "docName":"Document 2",
               "docUrl":"docName-2.pdf"
           },
           {
               "docName":"Document 3",
               "docUrl":"docName-3.pdf"
           }
       ],
       "id": 0
   }
   ```
4. When changes occur – maybe there's a change to a document's name, documents are added or removed, or dates change – the individual JSON objects are re-created and re-combined.

The JSON file has hundreds of objects and, what I'm having trouble with is inserting the "items" key in the correct object. For instance, objects with IDs 0-5 are created. "items" of ID=0 is modified. Update "items" of ID=0 and not 1-5.

#### The Question(s)

Using PHP or JavaScript, how can I link these two JSON objects correctly?

Would it be better to feed all of this information into a database (MySQL) and then construct the JSON file?

Comment: Short answer: yes, a database is more appropriate for this type of problem.

Comment: Yes, use a database. In any case, you need something that ties the data in step 2 with that in step 1 (an id, a name...).